# How to keep track or identify dynamic files in your storage bucket (cloud) via file name

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I want to have users upload files into my firebase storage. 
This works. However, I need to download all the files, and since the url endpoints are dynamic, I can't hardcode file paths.  Should I keep track of the file names in a database via firebase collection/documents database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is very common to use a database to track the contents of a storage bucket.  This makes the objects much easier to track via queries.

However, Cloud Storage also has a [list API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/listing-objects) that you can use the get a list of all the files.  That might be all you need.